# Django/Python: UnboundLocalError. where is my mistake?

Tags: python, django, view

models.py

```
class Revistapresei(models.Model):
    titlulArticol = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    textArticol = models.TextField()
    dataArticol = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    linkArticol = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)

    STIRIINTERNE = 'Interne'
    STIRIEXTERNE = 'Externe'
    TIP_ARTICOL_CHOICES = (
        (STIRIINTERNE, 'Interne'),
        (STIRIEXTERNE, 'Externe'),
    )
    tipArticol = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=TIP_ARTICOL_CHOICES, default=STIRIINTERNE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titlulArticol
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^revistaPresei/$', views.revistaPresei_list, name='revistaPresei_list'),
    url(r'^revistaPresei/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.revistaPresei_detail, name='revistaPresei_detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Revistapresei

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {})

def revistaPresei_list(request):
    revistaPreseis = Revistapresei.objects.order_by('-dataArticol')
    return render(request, 'blog/revistaPresei_list.html', {'revistaPreseis':revistaPreseis})

def revistaPresei_detail(request, pk):
    revistaPresei = get_object_or_404(revistaPresei, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/revistaPresei_detail.html', {'revistaPresei': revistaPresei})
```

revistaPresei_list.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Revista Presei List</title>
    </head>
<body>

{% for revistaPresei in revistaPreseis %}

<div>
    <p>{{ revistaPresei.dataArticol }} / {{ revistaPresei.tipArticol }}</p>
    <h1><a href="{% url 'revistaPresei_detail' pk=revistaPresei.pk %}">{{ revistaPresei.titlulArticol }}</a></h1>
    <p>{{ revistaPresei.textArticol }}</p>
</div>

{% endfor %}

</body>
```

revistaPresei_detail.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Revista Presei Detail</title>
    </head>
<body>
<div>
    {% if revistaPresei.titlulArticol %}
        <div>
            {{ revistaPresei.dataArticol }} / {{ revistaPresei.tipArticol }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <h1>{{ revistaPresei.titlulArticol }}</h1>
    <p>{{ revistaPresei.textArticol }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In case when I try to select an item in the file - revistaPresei_list.html - I recieve the error :

UnboundLocalError at /revistaPresei/1/
local variable 'revistaPresei' referenced before assignment ...

Tell me the correct answer in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `revistaPresei_detail(request, pk)` you have a wrong parameter in the call `revistaPresei = get_object_or_404(revistaPresei, pk=pk)`.

`get_object_or_404` wants the class name as the first parameter so you have to use `revistaPresei = get_object_or_404(Revistapresei, pk=pk)` (check the uppercase and lowercase letters).

At the moment you try to use the local variable `revistaPresei` as a parameter and this value doesn't exist at the time of the call which leads to the `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @Mircea, you might want to accept the answer if it is already perfect according to you...